# get touch coordinates (in the form of 0-480 and 0-320)

Tags: iphone, touch, coordinate-systems

i dont get how to translate the coordinates of the iphone.

if i make a single touch i get the coordinate.

if i make a touch and keep it and release it it shows the difference of the starting and end point.

how do i get the absolute position of the touch?

thanks!

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    NSLog(@"X: %f",location.x);
    NSLog(@"Y: %f",location.y);
}
```

I want to resize an image with touch and drag(only the height)

Comment: You should add your code getting coordinates (subclassing UIView ?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The position of a touch is calculated relative to a view.

If you want the position relative to the screen do:

```
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
NSLog(@"Position of touch: %.3f, %.3f", pos.x, pos.y);
```

(dry coded, might give errors)

Comment: thank you!
How is it possible to resize an UIImageVIew by dragging one side?

Comment: I've never used the UIImage classes. Have a look at the UIImage class refernce: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html . More specifically at `drawInRect:`

Comment: Isn't [touch locationInView:nil] gives the same result? The docs says: “Pass nil to get the touch location in the window’s coordinates.”

Comment: Pavel's comment is a better answer.   You are correct, according to Apple's UITouch documentation:   https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITouch/locationInView: